# Swift: Missing argument for parameter 'host' in call

Tags: swift

Here's my code:

```
class Search {


var url : NSURL!

 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {
    self.url = NSURL(string: searchBar.text)
    println(self.url)
    request()

}

func request() {

    var URL = NSURL(string: self.url!)
    let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: URL);
    feedParser.delegate = self
    feedParser.parse()
}
```

in `request()`, `var URL` returns the error

```
Missing argument for parameter "host" in call.
```

Any ideas how to solve this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just pass NsUrl at the Place of String. you can direct pass feedURL = self.url

```
 func request() {
        let feedParser = MWFeedParser(feedURL: self.url!);
        feedParser.delegate = self
        feedParser.parse()
}
```